# Probability of a uniform to be less than an exponential

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm trying to compute $\mathbb{P}[C<T]$ where $T$ is an exponential with parameter $\lambda$ and $C$ is a uniform on $[0,f]$. What I did :

$\mathbb{P}[C<T]=\int_{0}^{f}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{f}\,du\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt=\int_{0}^{f}\frac{t}{f}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt=\frac{\lambda}{f}\int_{0}^{f}te^{-\lambda t}\,dt=\frac{\lambda}{f}\left[\left[\frac{te^{-\lambda t}}{-\lambda}\right]_{0}^{f}-\int_{0}^{f}\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{-\lambda}\,dt\right]=\frac{\lambda}{f}\left[\frac{fe^{-\lambda f}}{-\lambda}+\frac{1}{\lambda}\left[\frac{1-e^{-\lambda f}}{\lambda}\right]\right]=-e^{-\lambda f}+\frac{1-e^{-\lambda f}}{\lambda f}$

While I should find only $\frac{1-e^{-\lambda f}}{\lambda f}$

I'm thinking of a mistake in my integration bounds maybe since I'm not able to find any mistake in my computation

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: You also add $\Pr(T > f)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot It's clear now !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account the fact that if $T>f$ it is certain that $C<T$.

More precisely :

$$P(C<T) = P(C<T \ \& \ T<f) + \underbrace{P(C<T \ \& \ T \ge f)}_{P(T \ge f)}$$

$$P(C<T) = \underbrace{P(C<T \ \& \ T<f)}_{\text{your computation}} + \underbrace{P(T \ge f)}_{e^{-\lambda f}}$$

explaining the final result.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I understand my mistake !